# How to use parentheses operators with BookshelfJS

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

Does anyone know how to use the SQL parentheses operators with the Bookshelf `Model`? (I know about the knex raw feature, but I'd like to use `Model` if it is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.  From the `Model`, it is possible to access knex `where` methods that provide for what's called "grouped chaining".

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-wheres